# Rails set protocol to always HTTP

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, nginx, devise, unicorn

I am running a Rails app inside of Vagrant. I am trying to run my app in QA mode to reflect my deployment environment. I am doing SSL termination at the load balancer in my QA environment, so I'd like to be able to run my Rails app only over http, no https anywhere.

I am using Devise for user authentication. I can load my app just fine, but when I log in, devise always wants to redirect onto https. I can't seem to get it to behave differently. I've pinged the devise maintainers for help but they didn't have any insight to share.

I've tried setting `config.force_ssl = false` but that doesn't seem to make a difference.

I am running the app under Unicorn, proxying to nginx. Any insight would be appreciated!

Comment: Could you solve this?

Comment: @vemw sadly, no, I never found a solution to this.

Answer (score 0):

I think adding something like thi to application.rb this might prevent the issue:

```
[
  config.action_controller.default_url_options,
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options,
  Rails.application.routes.default_url_options,
  Devise::Engine.routes.default_url_options,
  Devise::Engine.config.action_controller.default_url_options
].each do |config|

  config[:protocol] = "http#{'s' if Rails.env.production}"

end
```

In addition, you can override a variety of Devise controller methods, by subclassing them. So if you identify the cuplrit method, you can either a) solve the root cause, or b) subclass the controller, to use a workaround instead.